# Ext.reg('examplegrid', Example.Grid); ----->Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I always take this error when I write a regular expression like this:

```
Ext.reg('examplegrid', Example.Grid);
```

and getting this error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I think that I got this error because there is no function in this code but I found more extjs examples which has a code line like this.

Answer (score 0):

Which Ext version? `Ext.reg` was used in Ext 3.x, Ext 4 uses a different mechanism.